# Blow up and relationship between tangents sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

Let $X = \mathbb{P}^{n}$ and $Y \subset X$ a smooth subvariety of $X$.

Let us consider the blowup morphism of $X$ along of $Y$, denoted by $\pi : \widetilde{X} \longrightarrow X$ with exceptional divisor $E = \pi^{-1}(Y)$.

1) Is there any relationship between $T_{\widetilde{X}}$ and $T_{X}$?

If $c \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is a coherent sheaf in $X$, then :

2) Is it possible to write $T_{\widetilde{X}} \simeq \pi^{*}(T_{X}) \otimes \pi^{*}(\mathcal{F}) \otimes  \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}(cE)$?

3) Is there any relationship between $c$ and $\text{deg}(Y)$?

References on the subject and any help are welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Hi, Ultradark. Yes i tried and i'm trying.  I'm trying to use the exact sequences found in the book's : Intersection Theory, Lemma $ 15.4 $ (in my edition) but I still can't get a positive response.

Comment: @Ultradark. There must be good exact sequences to work on $\widetilde{X}$ that we haven't seen yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's an exact sequence $$0\to \pi^*\Omega^1_X\to \Omega^1_{\widetilde{X}}\to i_*\Omega^1_{E/Y}\to 0$$ where $i:E\to \widetilde{X}$ is the inclusion of the exceptional divisor. This corresponds to the fact that pulling back differential forms gives you differential forms which are constant along the fibers. Checking that this is exact may be done from looking at stalks: stalks of pullbacks are easy to compute, and stalks of direct images along closed immersions are easy to compute, plus each $\Omega^1$ is locally free on it's appropriate space, as everything involved here is smooth.

Taking $\mathcal{Hom}(-,\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}})$ of this exact sequence, we get the long exact sequence $$ 0\to \mathcal{Hom}(i_*\Omega^1_{E/Y},\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}) \to \mathcal{Hom}(\Omega^1_\widetilde{X},\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}) \to \mathcal{Hom}(\pi^*\Omega^1_X,\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}) \to \mathcal{Ext}^1(i_*\Omega^1_{E/Y},\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}})\to \cdots$$

and as $\mathcal{Hom}(-,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is exact on locally free sheaves, we see that $ \mathcal{Ext}^i(\pi^*\Omega^1_X,\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}})$ and $\mathcal{Ext}^i(\Omega^1_\widetilde{X},\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}})$ both vanish for $i>0$. As $i_*\Omega^1_{E/Y}$ is torsion, it's sheaf hom in to $\mathcal{O}_\widetilde{X}$ vanishes, and so all that's left to do is to identify $\mathcal{Ext}^1(i_*\Omega^1_{E/Y},\mathcal{O}_\widetilde{X})$. Replacing $i_*\Omega^1_{E/Y}$ with a locally free resolution locally isomorphic to $0\to\mathcal{O}_\widetilde{X}^d(-E)\to\mathcal{O}_\widetilde{X}^d\to 0$, we see the identification $\mathcal{Ext}^1(i_*\Omega^1_{E/Y},\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}})\cong i_*T_{E/Y}(E)$. So our long exact sequence reduces to $$0\to T_{\widetilde{X}}\to \pi^*T_X\to i_*T_{E/Y}(E)\to 0.$$

This is the correct relationship between $T_X$ and $T_\widetilde{X}$. It's completely independent of $Y$ as long as $Y$ is a smooth subvariety.

The correct setting for an equation like you ask for in (2) to hold is with the canonical sheaf of a blowup. Per Griffiths and Harris, for example, $\omega_{\widetilde{X}} \cong \pi^*\omega_X\otimes \mathcal{O}((c-1)E)$ where $c$ is the codimension of $Y$ in $X$ and $\omega_X=\bigwedge^{\dim{X}} \Omega^1_X$. Translating this in to tangent sheaves by dualizing and using the fact that dualizing commutes with taking determinant bundles (plus that $(\mathcal{O}(mE))^*=\mathcal{O}(-mE)$), we see that we should have $\bigwedge^nT_\widetilde{X}\cong (\bigwedge^nT_X)((1-c)E)$. There is no relation between $c$ and $\deg Y$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but there are some passages there that I still don't understand. Are they: 1) Why is the first sequence exact?  2) Is $c$ the codimension of exceptional divisor or $c = \text{codim}Y$? 3) And the last isomorphism? How did you get it? (I refer to isomorphism $\bigwedge^{n}T_{\widetilde{X}}$. Please could you further detail these items I mentioned so that your answer is as complete as possible? Again, Thank you very much.

Comment: I also didn't understand why when we dualize the first exact sequence, we get: $$0 \longrightarrow T_{\widetilde{X}} \longrightarrow \pi^{*}T_{X} \longrightarrow  i_{*}T_{E/Y} \longrightarrow 0 $$

Comment: Why $\text{ext}(i_{*} \Omega_{E/Y}) = 0$? Is $i_{*} \Omega_{E/Y}$ locally free sheaf? Thanks again for your complete answer, as such an answer will be helpful to many people.

Comment: 1. Check on stalks. The computations are straightforwards: stalks of pullbacks and stalks of pushforwards along closed immersions are easy to compute, and each of $\Omega^1_X,\Omega^1_{\widetilde{X}},\Omega^1_{E/Y}$ are locally free. 2. $c=\operatorname{codim}_X Y$, good catch - the codimension of the exceptional divisor is always 1, since it's a divisor. 3. Dualizing commutes with taking determinant bundles for locally free sheaves. All of this has been added to the post. An explanation for your 2nd comment has been added too. $i_*\Omega_{E/Y}$ is not locally free: it's torsion.

Comment: @KReiser. I didn't understand why $$\mathcal{H}\text{om}(i_{*}\Omega_{E/Y}, \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}) = 0$$ and $$\text{ext}^{1}(i_{*}\Omega_{E/Y}^{1},  \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}) \simeq  i_{*}T_{E/Y}(E)$$ Thank you in advance for your explanation.

Comment: you please detail what it means: replacing $i_{*}\Omega_{E/Y}^{1}$ with a locally free resolution isomorphic to $$0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}^{d}(-E) \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}^{d}\longrightarrow 0$$ Please ! Thank you.

Comment: @KReiser. Regarding the exact sequences, for me, it is clear now. Sorry, but I still don't understand isomorphism $$\bigwedge ^{n}T_{\widetilde{X}} \simeq (\bigwedge^{n}T_{X})((1-c)E)$$  Sorry for the inconvenience, but I'm being honest with you, I really didn't understand that isomorphism.

Comment: @Zlatan There's three parts. First, for any locally free sheaves $E,F$, we have that $(E\otimes F)^*=E^*\otimes F^*$. Applying that, we get that $(\pi^*\omega_X\otimes \mathcal{O}((c-1)E))^*=(\pi^*\omega_X)^*\otimes \mathcal{O}((c-1)E)^*$. The last term is exactly $\mathcal{O}((1-c)E)$. The first term should be $\pi^*(\omega_X^*)$, since dualizing commutes with pullback. Finally, as determinant and dualization commute, we see that $\omega_X^*=(\bigwedge^n\Omega^1_X)^*=(\bigwedge^n(\Omega^1_X)^*)=\bigwedge^n T_X$ (and also for $\widetilde{X}$ in place of $X$).

Comment: @AllanRamos The sheaf hom from any torsion sheaf in to any torsion free sheaf is zero, as the image of a torsion sheaf must be torsion. As $i_*\Omega^1_{E/Y}$ is torsion (it's supported on codim 1 subvariety), the result follows. Secondly, $\Omega^1_{E/Y}$ is locally free. So we can pick a neighborhood about any point on which it's isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{E}^d$. As we can calculate derived functors with acyclic objects and locally free sheaves are acyclic for sheaf hom, we can calculate with the specified resolution on any small enough neighborhood and then patch to get the result.

Comment: @KReiser. Thank you very much for your answer. Where can I find good material to learn all that you explained in this answer? Congratulations on the answer and once again, thank you very much.

Comment: @KReiser. Very Good. Excellent. Now it's very clear. As said user Allan Ramos, congratulations !!! Your answer will help many people!  Success to you. Thank you very much.

Comment: @KReiser. Are you all right? From isomorphism $$\bigwedge^{n}T_{\widetilde{X}} \simeq \bigwedge^{n}T_{X} \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}((c-1)E)$$ I can conclude that: $$\text{det}(T_{\widetilde{X}}) \simeq \text{det}(T_{X}) \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}((c-1)E)?$$ Sorry to bother you again with this question, but I had doubt reading your answer again. thank you very much.

Comment: @KReiser. Is the previous isomorphism valid for $ n = \text{dim}(X) $? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is the definition of the determinant of a line bundle plus the fact that the tangent bundle is free of rank $n$ if $X$ is smooth. Please do some searching next time before asking: for instance, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556980/semantics-determinant-bundle-top-exterior-power-of-vector-bundle/1558735) question and many other resources accessible via google will tell you this much quicker than posting a comment here.

Comment: (Please do some searching next time before asking). Again, I apologize for the inconvenience and thank you for responding.